# what is the fastest way to get performance metrics of all spring services?

Tags: java, performance, spring, frameworks, metric

what is the fastest way to get performance metrics of all spring services?

Comment: Give us more detail.  What kind of performance metrics?  Which spring services?  What platform / web container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [JAMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/) and apply the [`JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/JamonPerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html) on your services.

Comment: You could use JavaSimon instead which is being actively maintained and has a similar AOP Spring interceptor.  JAMon seems to have gone fallow.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try the [PerformanceMonitorInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/PerformanceMonitorInterceptor.html)?  You don't have to write anything that way, just configure it to advise all your service method calls.

Answer (score 1):

You'll prob need to quantify exactly what you want to get out of your application in terms fo performance metrics.  For a start though take a look at Beet, a performance and monitoring tool for Spring based apps:

http://beet.sourceforge.net/

There's also an article here than describes how to use Beet to gather performance metrics (such as method call timings):

http://www.gridshore.nl/2009/09/01/using-beet-to-monitor-your-spring-framework-application/

Comment: Beet is indeed interesting. However, official Spring 3.0 support has yet to be released.